# Tomcat - starting webapps in a specific order

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I know that Tomcat and the Servlet spec [do not support starting webapps in a particular order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504098/start-webapps-in-tomcat-in-a-determinate-order).

However, this seems to me like a common use case, and I'm wondering if someone has discovered a clever workaround for it.

I have webapp A which uses Spring Remoting to expose a shared service, of which webapp B is a client.  Webapp B cannot initialize unless webapp A is running.  However, my Tomcat is always starting the webapps linearly, starting with webapp B.

For infrastructure reasons I have to have these running on the same Tomcat server.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Roy

**UPDATE** -

Turns out that in my particular case, order doesn't matter.  The reason is this: say I use one of the methods below to start app A before app B.  So app A starts, but, since Spring remoting is using the HTTP Invoker, the HTTP port is not yet open (it won't open until *all* apps are started).  So A will start, and B will hang, because the port it's looking for is not yet available.  Doh.

End result was two separate Tomcat instances.

Comment: Have the web app that needs to wait for the other web app wait instead of failing and giving up.

Comment: Hey Dave, unf. they don't start in parallel.. B starts (well, tries to start) and then A will start after.  But if B can't start because it can't connect to A, A never tries to start.

Comment: It should start them in ASCII order. One trick that I see on Debian Apache installations is to create a 000_default, 001_default naming convention. That makes it a little clearer when viewing the ASCII order of the dir listing.

Comment: Comment to the UPDATE.
If your app A depends on another app B, then you should implement a Tomcat startup lifecycle listener as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22390818/callback-on-tomcat-server-startup-complete) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656052/how-to-detect-tomcat-startup-programmatically-from-within-a-servlet) and finish the app initialization once the Tomcat AFTER_START_EVENT is received.

Comment: Your updated question has worked for me too, thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have the same problem and to solve it we're relying on the fact (slippery, I know) that applications are started in the order they are defined in `<tomcat_home>/conf/server.xml`.

This of course has a disadvantage of hardcoding apps in the `server.xml` but we can live with it.

Comment: Thanks mindas - This is probably the 'best' way to do it but unf doesn't work for me - I'll edit my question to explain why.

Comment: I strongly prefer to avoid changes in code. With this config we add apps to Context, which should be started first( net-config-api,ConfigServer), or in strict order , but also enable autoDeploy in order to dynamically deploy apps not specified in Context. In tomcat/conf/server.xml:
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
       autoDeploy="true" deployOnStartup="false" 
      deployIgnore=".*ConfigServer.*|.*net-config-api.*">
      <Context path="/net-config-api" docBase="net-config-api" reloadable="true"/>
      <Context path="/ConfigServer" docBase="ConfigServer" reloadable="true"/>>

Comment: My config solves very similar problem as the author has. The deployOnStartup="false" avoids that tomcat blocks networking until all app finish start. Here ConfigServer provides config to other config clients - which waits the response. Add also startStopThreads="8" - because client app blocks its thread, tomcat must provide more start threads than count of blocking clients, otherwise configServer start could be blocked by client threads.

Answer (score 6):

That's quite easy to achieve if you don't care hacking a bit of tomcat code and creating your own Host instance

1) Create a subClass of org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost, say MyHost:

```
    class MyHost extends org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost{
        public MyHost (){
        super();
        //changing HashMap for a predictable ordered Map :)
        this.children = new LinkedHashMap();
        }
    }
```

2) register your class on your server's xml Host tag ()

Incredible as it may seem, it solves the problem as long as you have all your web app declared in the correct order inside of Host tag:

```
    <Host>
     <context app1>
     <context app2>
   </Host>
```

Thaen app1 will start before app2, no matter which SO you used.

Comment: After first step, where should we put MyHost class? Can you please elaborate more.

Comment: can we have example of the host configuration

Comment: This no longer works in Tomcat 9 because the `children` field is final.

Answer (score 6):

Here is another trick on Linux.

Some of our webservice applications fail to deploy, because of erroneous WSDL.  This happens if they are deployed or started after a number of other applications.
The order in which they are started depends on the order in which context xml's are found in  /opt/apache-tomee/conf/Catalina/localhost

Can be verified using  "`ls -1f`".  A plain "ls" gives a sorted output.

This used to be the order in which files were added to that directory, but with ext4 filesystems, the order is based on a hash of the filename.  This can be disabled as follows:

```
# tune2fs -O ^dir_index /dev/xyz
```

Now you can at least decide yourself in which order they will be started.  Reordering: move all files to a temporary folder, move them back in the desired sequence.

Comment: Just found this trick in the wild. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: I don't know about the "fragility".  I ran a Tomcat hosting 50 apps this way, and wasn't in the habit of rebooting Tomcat without a good reason.   Also, it wasn't my intention to beat the transparancy of Tomcat itself.

Answer (score 6):

Old thread, but...

Another way to work around this is to create a custom HostConfig class which sorts the web apps the way you need.

```
public class OrderedHostConfig extends HostConfig {

    @Override
    protected String[] filterAppPaths(String[] unfilteredAppPaths) {
        String[] files = super.filterAppPaths(unfilteredAppPaths);
        Arrays.sort(files, compare());
        return files;
    }

    private Comparator<String> compare() {
        return (o1, o2) -> {
        // Your own implementation 
        };
    }
}
```

Then you can reference this class in your server.xml under the Host definition.

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" hostConfigClass="your.package.OrderedHostConfig">
```

You need to compile this into a jar and save it in Tomcat's /lib directory. In my case:

> /var/lib/tomcat8/lib

I like this method because:

1. The order is enforced only where it's relevant, but there is no need to manage all the webapps manually in Host definitions using Context
2. Searching for the .war file name in the codebase will also reference this class, which makes it easier to find if the file is renamed.
3. No changing of private final fields for tomcat 8, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29684918/tomcat-8-starting-webapps-in-a-given-order)

Comment: This is actually a great solution. Tested on Tomcat 8.5 and 9.x and it works well.

Comment: @mvreijn Have you tested? I'm not sure if this works for 9.x, at least for Tomcat v9.0.19 it does not work. It's not in the official Tomcat API docs either.

Comment: @wzona yes I have tested as mentioned. However, behavior may have changed, or could have been a coincidence.

Answer (score 3):

Since none of the options worked for Tomcat 9.0.19 (the one mentioned by @Luiz also) we used the code approach and replaced the Tomcat StandardHost and HostConfig with minimal custom implementations:

```
public class CustomTomcatHost extends StandardHost {

    public CustomTomcatHost() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void addLifecycleListener(LifecycleListener listener) {
        if (listener instanceof HostConfig) {
            listener = new OrderedHostConfig();
        }
        super.addLifecycleListener(listener);
    }
}
```

The **deployApps** function in *HostConfig* had to be overriden for sorting to work for everything (incl. WAR files in /webapps folder and also for descriptor XML files in configbase folder (e.g. conf/Catalina/localhost)):

```
public class OrderedHostConfig extends HostConfig {

    public OrderedHostConfig() {
        super();
    }

    public String[] prioritySort(String[] paths) {
        if (paths == null) return null;

        Arrays.sort(paths, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String a, String b) {
                return a.compareTo(b); //TODO: sort paths based on your criteria
            }
        });

        return paths;
    }

    @Override
    protected void deployApps() {

        File appBase = host.getAppBaseFile();
        File configBase = host.getConfigBaseFile();

        String[] apps = prioritySort(filterAppPaths(appBase.list()));

        // Deploy XML descriptors from configBase
        deployDescriptors(configBase, prioritySort(configBase.list()));
        // Deploy WARs
        deployWARs(appBase, apps);
        // Deploy expanded folders
        deployDirectories(appBase, apps);
    }
}
```

Then we placed the new classes in a new jar file in Tomcat /lib directory and modified conf/server.xml file to replace the host class with our own implementation:

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" className="com.example.CustomTomcatHost" >
```

During start Tomcat loaded all components in the required order.

Comment: I can confirm this works. The solution posted by @Luiz looked like it worked locally and was extensively tested but for some reason did *not* work on GitHub (in the same Docker container as locally) ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. This, on the other hand, did!

Answer (score 1):

In theory you could spawn a `Runnable` by `ExecutorService` in `contextInitialized()` which in turn checks the availability of the other webapp at timed intervals (perhaps by firing a HTTP `HEAD` request?). Once the other webapp is available, then set some attribute in the servlet context which indicates that. Add a `Filter` which checks for the presence of that attribute and blocks/continues requests accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old, but I found it when trying to do the same thing and thought I'd update with a better solution...

You can define mulitple services in your server.xml, which run on different ports. The services are started sequentially according to the order they appear in the server.xml. This means that you can have - for example - a configuration service running in the first service and then the apps that depend on it in the second (I use the default Catalina one for the rest of them...)

You can see more info here:
http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Miscellaneous#Q27

And this is the service that I include *before* the Catalina Service:

```
<Service name="ConfigService">
    <Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
        connectionTimeout="20000"
        redirectPort="8444" />
    <Engine name="ConfigServiceEngine" defaultHost="localhost">
        <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
            xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">

            <Context path="/" reloadable="true" docBase="/path/to/your/service/directory" />
        </Host>
    </Engine>
</Service>
```

As you can see, I use docbase rather than appBase, but you should be able t configure a different appBase if you prefer...

NB it's important to change the name of both the service and the engine.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice trick i use to create 2 levels of webapp loading. in each level the order is not guaranteed. This relies on the fact that tomcat will load first context descriptors from tomcat/conf/[Engine Name]/[Host Name] and only then contexts from the appBase attribute of the Host element in server.xml

Just add the following code somewhere in the webapp you would like to load in the 2nd level ( i.e. later )

```
File contextDescriptor = new File(getParameter("catalina.home"),"/conf/Catalina/localhost/mywebapp.xml");
contextDescriptor.deleteOnExit();
```

Answer (score -1):

Can it be that they are starting in the order as they are deployed in?

So if i have four apps: 1, 2, 3, 4 and i deploy them in the following order: 1, 2, 4 (restart tomcat), 3 (restart). That it caches something somewhere to make the projects always startup in that order? So 1, 2, 4, 3. It happens over here. I'm unsure, but maybe it helps someone.