# Tomcat 8: Starting WebApps in a given order

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8

Using Tomcat 8.0.15 with Java 8

I need a certain WebApp to load first so I put the following in my server.xml:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true" className="com.my.class.MyCustomHost">
    <Context docBase="app_to_load" path="/app_to_load"/>
</Host>
```

MyCustomHost looks like below:

```
public class MyCustomHost extends StandardHost {
    public MyCustomHost () {
        super();
        this.children = new LinkedHashMap();
    } }
```

This setup worked in Tomcat 7.0.42 (with Java 7) but in Tomcat 8.0.15 (with Java 8), I get the following error:

> Apr 16, 2015 3:36:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester
>   startElement SEVERE: Begin event threw error
>   java.lang.IllegalAccessError  at
>   com.my.class.MyCustomHost.(MyCustomHost.java:18)

The solution I am trying to use was derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793891/tomcat-starting-webapps-in-a-specific-order).  Any input would help! Thanks!

Comment: I think that might be problem with Tomcat version. Look over here : https://community.jivesoftware.com/thread/265007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`children` is a `final` field in Tomcat 8 (see this source code [diff](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc8.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/core/ContainerBase.java?r1=1357413&r2=1360910)), so changing it is illegal. Fortunately, you can use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4516608/3080094) to set it to a `LinkedHashMap`, or use the referred [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/3080094) (with some small changes) to make `children` non-final.