# How to detect Tomcat Startup Programmatically from within a Servlet?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jakarta-ee, tomcat7, tomcat8

**Question**

How can you programmatically determine when Tomcat has completed startup? I mean programmatically from within a WAR file running on Tomcat, most likely via a Servlet that can tap into container info if possible?

**Background**

The Catalina log entry that you normally see after a WAR has fully deployed would be equal to what I'm looking for. I have a constraint that makes parsing the logs undesirable. But the data that goes to Catalina.out is precisely what I'm looking for. I'm trying to find a way to go a layer above the servlet, maybe even higher, to obtain container status with regards to Startup time but I'm open to alternate methods if they are possible.

**What I've Tried**

I tried detecting servlet initialization but thats specific to components inside the WAR and not the servlet container itself. I also tried Spring Events but the highest level they provide are "Application Contexts" which only indicate a group of Spring Beans have finished loading and not necessarily even all Spring beans...If theres a solution thats closer to the Servlet Spec or a Tomcat specific library that would be appreciated.

Comment: What, specifically, are you trying to do? What "container information" do you want?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz "How to detect Tomcat Startup"...As expressed in my 1st line. The same startup event thats sent to Catalina.out at the very end of all initialazation logic.

Comment: What if your application is deployed after Tomcat starts up? Then there is no startup event to detect. Do you want to know when the sockets are bound? Do you want to know exactly when requests are able to be routed to your application? Do you want to know the time it took Tomcat to be ready to accept requests after the JVM launched? It's really unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Are you familiar with the Startup time event that is sent to Catalina.out at the end of startup?

Comment: I'm quite familiar with it. So specifically you are asking to find out the startup-time of Tomcat? It's entirely possible that Tomcat has completed its startup before the application is deployed. What should happen in that situation?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz For my use-case a deployment involves shutting down Tomcat before uploading a new WAR file so that Tomcat and the app start together. So your second question isn't a scenario we are dealing with. For more context read the section of my question labeled "Background" where I go into detail about what I mean by startup time. Following GSL's post below I'm now using external Tomcat LifeCycle events to detect the "after_start" event. This runs in a custom jar I put in Tomcat lib. The answer I was hoping for was something I could do from within a WAR but this does the job.

Comment: Tomcat does not always wait for all applications to deploy before accepting requests. Warning: this solution may be fragile.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz Thats good to know. Thanks for the warning.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz I won't be making decisions based on "network readiness" this was more a need to track how the Tomcat lifecycle transitions are being slowed by ever increasing war file sizes. Metrics essentially. But I will remember your caution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A Servlet is only executing if Tomcat has fully completed it's startup** and is running and processing requests. So, sorry but, the question does not make sense. (It's like you can't answer the question "Are you awake?" with "no" truthfully.)

All that runs of a Web Application before Tomcat startup is completed, is any `ServletContextListener` that you implemented and registered (in `server.xml`). When the application has been started by Tomcat, it calls the contextInitialized() method of any registered `ServletContextListener`.

If you want some code to be executed around the Tomcat lifecycle, you could use Tomcat's `org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener` interface. Implement this in an own class and register the class in `server.xml` at a Service, Engine or Host. Such a class will not reside in your webapp, but is deployed in the `lib` directory of Tomcat (something like that; check for your version of Tomcat).

Conceptually, one Web Application can never know of any other Web Application in the same Servlet Container (i.e. Tomcat); this is strictly prohibited by the specification. There are no methods to connect two apps in any way. In Tomcat, there is the exception of a "**privileged**" application, such as the **Tomcat Manager**. If you define an application as privileged, it does have certain means to deal with other webapps.

Comment: I'll look into the LifeCycleListener registration. You're 1st comment is not entirely true. A servlet will not handle requests before Startup complete but you can put initialization logic inside its init method and that will run before completion. I have an application with thousands of Java beans firing thousands of function calls almost 20 seconds before startup completes. The LifeCycleListener that you mention might be what I'm looking for. I'll follow up if it works.

Comment: Ah, right. I didn't think of the init() method. I never use it.

Comment: Nice work man. This works like a charm. Simple jar file I drop in Tomcat lib and register in Server.xml and tells me exactly when things complete and matches the log entries.