# Tomcat... web app startup order

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-jmx

Is it possible to determine the start up order in Tomcat... have app1 wait for another app2 to finish deploying.

I have read the docs that suggest Tomcat does not allow any guarantees.... but using spring apps is it possible to determine when an app has been deployed... and then have the sub apps which have been deployed listen for the main app to fire an event that will trigger them to start up - init..

any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504098/start-webapps-in-tomcat-in-a-determinate-order

Comment: What is your requirement/problem?

Comment: @Ravi.. yes it is... october the 9th 2009. thought maybe something has been found... My requirement is i need one app1 to start before  app2 otherwise a race condition can occur...

Comment: I am not fully aware of your requirement but it is not possible in tomcat but you might use 'load-on-startup', you can post your problem/requirement, and might get better solution

Comment: how about using jmx.. and using listeners?.... would that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no tomcat does not support this.

There is no possible way to order it.